# How do I sync contacts who are not members in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, contacts, import, acl

My client organization only has organizational members, but provides services and events to individuals connected to the organization. The WP Member sync, seems limited to only syncing members.

I need to create users who are associates of member organizations. Those are mostly 1 to many type relationships. I have some that are many to many type relationships. This is my last step and I hadn't realized there wasn't an obvious path here. What is the proper way to proceed to import these users?

Comment: Im am currently just guessing (no expert on this subject), but the documentation (https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/membership/online-membership-sign-up/) says: "Organisational memberships:
The title tab contains a check box to allow people to become members on behalf of an organisation, which is the recommended way to offer organisational memberships. (...) Organisational sign up can either be optional or required." - Are you signing up the organisations directly or do you already use the indicated way?

Comment: The issue is the consequences (roles and permissions) that come from the type of membership. The users of one type of member gets anonymity, but the users who work with the second type of member organization gets publicly listed. They also get separate pricing for events. So the type membership cascades throughout the system. I think I resolved this, at least in the near term. Hopefully, it won't bite me in the butt later.

Answer (score 1):

There are two solutions:

1) You can set the Organization Membership to "trickle down" via a relationships. This is hard to change after the fact. You will need to update the Membership type via the database and then manually update all the Memberships.

2) You can create an advanced search pulling all the Organization Memberships and set the Display Results As: Related Contacts. Make that into a Smart Group. Use that Smart Group or most likely multiple Smart Groups into a Group Role Sync via your plugin.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the best solution, but I figured that I should report back, in case anyone else can benefit from my experience. In short, I created new user roles in WordPress that correspond to my key contact types, because I was going to need this for ACL anyway. I exported my smart groups with enough information to import the records as new users into WordPress and then I synced the contacts with the WordPress users. So far (it's only been a day) nothing has blown up in my face and the testing is going well. I think we go live later today.